# how to send page template on single page for access only single content

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a page home and made a "template-home" for it which is selected.

The problem is that I want to send this page on page.php to read more content. I have use the permmalink function in template-home.php to send to page.php but this is not working - it redirects to the home URL.

```
page->Home
     >template-home.php
```

Comment: Could you provide your code?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `->template-home.php` ??